# org mode spreadsheet formula for the number of lines in a cell

Tags: emacs, spreadsheet, org-mode

I am looking at a `org-mode` spreadsheet formula to get the number of non-empty lines in a cell. Example :

```
| col1 | col2 |
|------+------|
| a    |  3   |
| b    |      |
| c    |      |
|      |      |
|------+------|
| a    |  1   |
|      |      |
|------+------|
| a    |  2   |
| b    |      |
|      |      |
|------+------|
```

I have "col1" as input, and would like to fill "col2" automatically (the values can be anything, not just a b c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that what you call *"cell"* is actually a group of cells delimited by horizontal separators (*hlines*).

The following example uses calc's `vlen` function to get the size of the vector of cells on column 1, and rows between the previous (`@-I`) and next (`@+I`) hlines.

```
| col1 | col2 |
|------+------|
| a    | 3    |
| b    |      |
| c    |      |
|      |      |
|------+------|
#+TBLFM: @2$2=vlen(@-I$1..@+I$1)
```

You have to apply this same formula for all row groups.

Comment: Do I have to do something to make it update ? It doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: You can use [commands for recalculating](http://orgmode.org/manual/Updating-the-table.html) the table, or add tags for [automatic recalculation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-features.html).

Comment: Thanks. Any tips for duplicating the formula along the several lines ?

Comment: I can't find anything more elegant than copy-paste the formula several times in the formula line. Something like `#+TBLFM: @2$2=vlen(@-I$1..@+I$1)::@6$2=vlen(@-I$1..@+I$1)`